# .Net DLL referencing another DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, typelib

I have one .Net 4.0 dll project that references third party PDF converter DLL. I have exposed this dll for COM. Now when I am trying to add my .tlb file to VB6 project it comes up with runtime error. Error says the dll which is third party pdf converter cannot be found.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Many Thanks
Ni

Comment: Kudos to you for even trying to do all that...

Comment: Try turning on Assembly Binding Logging. It may help you diagnose your problem. Using [Fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx) is the easiest way to turn it on.

Comment: How complicated is the VB6 project?  Can you ditch it / rewrite it?

Comment: actually that is very big project. Problem I am trying to solve is: I have got old very important product in vb6. Now i need to convert HTML pages in PDF. but most of all converters cannot be used with VB. therefore I developed DLL and added to VB6 project. But when I run the project it is trying to find third party pdf converter dll.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: what do you mean. Sorry I am not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Nirali - Why wouldn't you just import the DLL in question within your VB6 code?

Comment: @Nirali Assembly Binding Logging logs all attempts to load a dll or exe by the CLR. It includes the paths where its looking. This may help you figure out your problem. Note: I'm making an assumption that the CLR loads a dll when a ref gets made from VB 6. I could be wrong about that

Comment: @Ramhound. I tried that but VB6 wouldnt let me add .Net4.0 dll (PDF converter DLL is in .Net 4.0) directly. It doesnt have .tlb file.

Comment: @Conrad Frix. Oh ok. Thanks for that. However, I havent added third party dll in VB6 project as it want let me add it. So, I am not sure if Binding logging logs with help me.

Comment: @Nirali right but the COM Callable .NET project does ref the PDF Converter

Comment: Is this 3 party dll in the same folder as your .Net COM Wrapper?

You can also use ProcessMonitor to monitor all attempts to load the DLL (this can help you to narrow the problem a little bit)

Comment: Ok at last it worked. All I did: open up .tlb file in Visual studio and added third party pdf dll using custom library. It started working.. Thanks everyone for help....

Comment: @Nirali - can you post an answer to that effect and accept it?

Comment: @Jeremy: actually I tried but as i have less than 100 reputation, I am not allowed to answer my own question before 7 hours :( but will do it after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok at last it worked. All I did: open up .tlb file in Visual studio and added third party pdf dll using custom library. It started working.. Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VB6 dates from the days of DLL Hell.  There's no good scenario to help the CLR find the DLL in some random directory when the VB6 IDE is in charge.  It isn't clear whether the helper DLL is a .NET assembly or a native DLL.  Either way, what works best is copying the DLL into the same directory as vb6.exe, `c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb98` by default.  Keeping that copy up to date is your bit of dll hell.

Comment: Note that you will need to be an Administrator to write in the Program Files folder and that in general, writing in Program Files is frowned upon if not during an installation.

Comment: Yes, a programmer messing with a user's Program Files is not nice.  A programmer messing with *his own* Program Files is of course not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either GAC the third party dll, or put it in the same path as the registered COM dll

Comment: Ok at last it worked. All I did: open up .tlb file in Visual studio and added third party pdf dll using custom library. It started working.. Thanks for your help....

Comment: That only seems like it works.  Your next problem is debugging the vb6 code.  Still can't find the dll.

Comment: @HansPassant yes you are right. but I needed a quick fix for UAT. so I am not worried about that at present. But will need to diagnose the problem in future

Comment: @Nirali: Please don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied.